# How to Control HID Output from RFID Reader

Tags: vb.net, rfid, hid-device

i have 2 rfid readers that communicate with HID Driver. and 2 rfid tags with value 0008478651 and 0008776392. When I swap one tag to first rfid reader it's work perfectly, the result showing 0008478651 in notepad, but when I swap 2 of them in 2 rfid reader, the result shows 00008700847876653921. 
I found that the rfid reader send value one by one character to notepad, so when second tag swaped and notepad hasnot finished shows all first tag value's characters, then notepad will read second tag on first value tag's not finisihed character.

So, to handle this I want to know how to control HID output to send rfid value per full characters.

by the way, actually I use rfid to develop vbnet application

Comment: It sounds like you're sending both readers' outputs to the same instance of Notepad. The two readers have no knowledge of each other, and so they output strings at the same time. In that respect, everything is working correctly. You may want to consider an alternative, like outputting each reader to a separate TextBox control.

Comment: thanks for your answer Ryan, but the problem is I don't know how to separate the output from each readers in vbnet. I just use textbox.focus to get the output value. Do you know component that can seperate the output from hid device Ryan?

Comment: If the readers use a generic HID driver that basically operates like a keyboard wedge (sending keystrokes as if it were a keyboard input), there might not be an easy way to do this. Did the readers come with alternate drivers or an SDK? If not, you may be able to use the Windows API to communicate directly to them. Making API calls from VB.Net is not always a walk in the park, though, so you'll probably need lots of research. There are also existing projects you can leverage for communication, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18099/A-USB-HID-Component-for-C).